# 3 tables joining using left join in mysql

Tags: mysql, join

I have total 4 tables. The data below is dummy data but the structure is same with my original db.

```
Table -- ms1    Table -- ms2          Table -- ms3

msoneid         mstwoid               msthreeid
3               11                    79
4               12                    83
5               14                    84
6               17                    85

Master table -- ms

rid                hid                   tie
11                 3                     33
11                 5                     44
12                 12                    55
12                 84                    66
13                 79                    77
13                 17                    88
```

What I want

```
hid           tie
3             33
4             0
5             44
6             0
11            0
12            55
14            0
17            88
79            77
83            0
84            66
85            0
```

My query is

`select * from ms where rid in (11,12,13)` and this is not giving me the other absent ids which are in other 3 tables obviously because it's not joined.I tried with left join but I messed it up.

Any help/hint/example is highly welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a union query would work here

```
SELECT ms1.msoneid as hid, ms.tie FROM ms1 LEFT JOIN ms ON ms1.msoneid=ms.hid WHERE ms.rid in(11,12,13)
UNION
SELECT ms2.mstwoid as hid, ms.tie FROM ms2 LEFT JOIN ms ON ms2.mstwoid=ms.hid WHERE ms.rid in(11,12,13)
UNION
SELECT ms3.msthreeid as hid, ms.tie FROM ms3 LEFT JOIN ms ON ms3.msthreeid=ms.hid WHERE ms.rid in(11,12,13)
```

Here's a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af0885/1)

To sort the records you could make the series of queries above a sub query.

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT ms1.msoneid as hid, ms.tie FROM ms1 LEFT JOIN ms ON ms1.msoneid=ms.hid WHERE ms.rid in(11,12,13)
  UNION
  SELECT ms2.mstwoid as hid, ms.tie FROM ms2 LEFT JOIN ms ON ms2.mstwoid=ms.hid WHERE ms.rid in(11,12,13)
  UNION
  SELECT ms3.msthreeid as hid, ms.tie FROM ms3 LEFT JOIN ms ON ms3.msthreeid=ms.hid WHERE ms.rid in(11,12,13)
) as tempTbl 
ORDER BY tempTbl.hid;
```

Comment: Thanks Robbert. Let me try with it.Also I have to use a where clause for the rids?

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much. Is there any way to mention the rids within each select.

Comment: Sure, just include ms.rid in the select for each query.  I've updated the query

Comment: Sorry actually what I meant to say is that if it possible to add a where clause for eg where rid in (11,12,13) before each union.

Comment: Oh, yes. each query is independent of each other. The only thing is the columns must match.  So you can make each where clause whatever you want.

Comment: Just wondering if I can use order by. I tried but it's giving an error.So before each union I tried 'order by hid'

Comment: You can make this a sub query.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks once again. It helped a lot.

Comment: I have modified the whole query a little bit. I have added a sum and group by function and working fine. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
select      alias_master.* 
from        ms alias_master
left join   ms1 alias_ms1 on alias_master.rid = alias_ms1.msoneid
left join   ms2 alias_ms2 on alias_master.rid = alias_ms2.mstwoid
left join   ms3 alias_ms3 on alias_master.rid = alias_ms3.msthreeid
where       ms.rid in(11,12,13)
```

not sure if i get what you mean, but this might help.